# ¿Problema en php para cambiar la contraseña en início de sesión?

Tags: php, mysql

estoy tratando de verificar la contraseña actual del usuario para luego proceder al cambio del mismo pero siempre me dice contraseña actual incorrecta y no me deja avanzar en el código, lo que quisiera logra es esto: si el usuario ingresa una contraseña que no es igual a la que tiene guardada en la base de datos debe dar el error:`('Contraseña Actual Incorrecta')`, si el usuario ingresa una contraseña igual a la guardada en la base de datos debe decir: `('La Contraseña nueva Ingresada es igual a la anterior')`, si el usuario ingresa una  Contraseña Nueva y no es igual a la Confirmación de la Contraseña debe dar el error `('Las contraseñas ingresadas no coinciden')`, de todo estar correcto el mensaje final sería `('Contraseña cambiada correctamente.')` anexo el código a ver en qué estoy fallando.

```
<!--Validar-->
<?php 

session_start(); 

include '../conexion/conexion.php';// incluímos los datos de conexión a la BD 


if(isset($_SESSION['Usuario'])) { // comprobamos que la sesión esté iniciada
    if(isset($_POST['enviar'])) {        
        $usuario = $_SESSION['usuario'];     
        $clave = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["clave"], $link);
        $sql_clave_actual = "SELECT clave FROM usuario WHERE clave='".$clave."' LIMIT 1";
        $exec = mysql_query($sql_clave_actual,$link);

        if(mysql_num_rows($exec) == 0) {
           echo "<script>alert ('Contraseña Actual Incorrecta');</script>
           <META HTTP-EQUIV='REFRESH' CONTENT=0;URL=http:miclave.php>";          
        } else {
            $fila = mysql_fetch_array($sql_clave_actual);  
            if ($clave_actual == $fila['clave']) {
                echo "<script>alert ('La Contraseña nueva Ingresada es igual a la anterior');</script>
           <META HTTP-EQUIV='REFRESH' CONTENT=0;URL=http:miclave.php>";
            } else {
                if($_POST['clave'] != $_POST['usuario_clave_conf']) {
                    echo "<script>alert ('Las contraseñas ingresadas no coinciden');</script>
          <META HTTP-EQUIV='REFRESH' CONTENT=0;URL=http:miclave.php>";
                } else {
                    $usuario = $_SESSION['usuario']; 
                    $clave = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["clave"]);
                    $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE usuario SET clave='".$clave."' WHERE usuario='".$usuario."'");
                    if($sql) {
                        echo "<script>alert ('Contraseña cambiada correctamente.');</script>
              <META HTTP-EQUIV='REFRESH' CONTENT=0;URL=http:miclave.php>";
                    }  else {
                        echo "<script>alert ('Error: No se pudo cambiar la contraseña.');</script>
              <META HTTP-EQUIV='REFRESH' CONTENT=0;URL=http:miclave.php>"; 
                    }  
                }
            }
        }
    }
} else {
    header('Location: ../index.php');
    echo "<script>alert('Disculpe Acceso registringido')</script>";
    exit(); 
} 
?>
```

Comment: No puedo cambiar de contraseña no recuerda la actual

Comment: Deberías de guardar las contraseñas cifradas en la base de datos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece que el error esta en:

```
if ($clave_actual == $fila['clave'])
```

en tu script hay una variable  `$sql_clave_actual` y `$clave` pero no logre encontrar `$clave_actual` y el error puede ser ese.

Comment: en el formulario lo tengo así:  
`<input type="password" name="clave_actual" required/>Contraseña Actual
<input type="password" name="clave" required/>Contraseña Nueva
<input type="password" name="usuario_clave_conf" required/>Confirme Contraseña`

Comment: entonces es una variable del POST y deberias llamarla desde POST['clave_actual'] y no $clave_actual, creo yo.

Comment: ya lo solucione tendría que quedar asi: `$clave = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['clave_actual'], $link);`, ahora lo unico que no se sirve en el código es `('La Contraseña nueva Ingresada es igual a la anterior')` si en los tres campos pongo la misma contraseña que seria la contraseña actual no me dice ese mjs

Comment: Eso que dices, deberías evaluar antes de enviar los datos del formulario.

Comment: si pero el error me lo da es aquí  `if ($clave_actual == $fila['clave']) { `

Comment: asigna la variable `$clave_actual = $_POST['clave_actual']` para poder usarla en el if o cambia el if a `if ($_POST['clave_actual'] == $fila['clave'])`, la verdad no recuerdo si se puede hacer `$fila['clave']` intenta cambiar a `fila[0]` o `fila[1]` utilizando el número indice.